# UITableView form

Tags: iphone, forms, uitableview

I am having very annoying issue. I have one form page with 5 custom cells. Each of them has one text field. On the bottom I have one button. In an onclick button function I am gathering values from each of the 5 described text fields.
My problem is that if my keyboard is up, I will get the values of not all but just visible text fields, the ones I don't see are null.

How to override this?

Thx,
Mladen

Answer (score 5):

Separate data you have from your interface, that is store your textfield values in some other place right after you finish input. And access your data there. 

       UI elements are not intended to **store** data, but just to **display** it and allow input - as you can see in your case if you do not see a particular element you cannot be sure that it actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem.. 
 1. Register your viewcontroller for KeboardNotifications
2.When keyboard will appear resize the view so that all fields will be visible.
 
 3. When keboard will disappear just resize it back and continue..